# Calling a function in form

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have three forms ProfileForm.js, ProfileTab.js and ItemTab.js. ProfileTab is inherting(extending class) from Items.js.

Here is a ProfileTab.js

```
Example.Portal.ProfilesTab = Ext.extend(Example.Portal.ItemTab, {
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(this, {
            gridConfig: {
                title: 'Profile Templates',
                width: 260,
                xtype: 'example.portal.profilesgrid'
            },
            panelConfig: {
                title: 'Profile Template',
                xtype: 'example.portal.profileform'
            }
        });
        Example.Portal.ProfilesTab.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});

Ext.reg('example.portal.profilestab', Example.Portal.ProfilesTab);
```

ProfileForm is used as a 'xtype'. I m trying to add a function in ItemTab.js which can be used in ProfileForm.js.

I have already tried adding a function in ItemTab.js, but I cannot access it inside ProfileForm.

Any help would be appreciated. I am in learning phase, please do not downgrade this question.

Comment: You tried `this.some_func()`? Should be there. Maybe your `this` is pointing to the wrong thing, print it out and see if you are in the right scope.

Comment: Yes I already did that. I can access this.some_func() in ItemTab and ProfileTab, but not in ProfileForm

Comment: So ProfileForm is not inheriting anything? Then why do you feel you should be able to access some unrelated code from it, or I am missing something. xtype doesn't mean anything, it could be `xtype:button`, button won't be able to access your other files either.

Comment: ProfileForm is inheriting Ext.Panel where I have defined Save button. I m trying to have a 'Save' function inside ItemTab, so that I can access this  around any form inherting ItemTab class. I have multiple files which are using ItemTab.js

Answer (score 0):

For those who wants to have something similar, I have solved this problem by adding a listener event in ItemTab.js and have used fireEvent() in ProfileForm.js.